# Arrows do not align with the number of the x and y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I want my lines/arrows to be align with the number of the x and y axis. I am new to the matplot library so I have little knowledge about it.

```
from numpy import array

from math import *

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

u = [1,0]

v = [0,1]

ax = plt.axes()

ax.set_xlim([-1,5])
ax.set_ylim([-1,5])

ax.quiver(0,0,u[0],u[1],color='red')

ax.quiver(0,0,v[0],v[1],color='blue')

plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgOIt.png)

Comment: If not specified, the value will be 0.5, and each must be specified with a scale and so on. Try this. And see [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html). `ax.quiver(0,0,u[0],u[1],color='red', angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)`

Comment: Thank you, just tried it and it works. Also thanks for the link.